# element initialization causing app crash

Tags: java, android

so I'm working on a personalized app that does a bunch of calculations.
when I initialize the elements the app crashes and if I don't initialize any of the element the app shows the layout just fine and does some basic function of which I have added methods of using onClick attribute in XML

I need to extract the data from the EditText elements in using to make calculations.

java code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

//setting up the elements
EditText finInv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.finInv);
String finInvString= finInv.getText().toString();
int investment=Integer.parseInt(finInvString);

Button button14=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);

EditText rawBroRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.bronzeRate));

EditText rawSilRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.silverRate));

EditText rawGoldRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.goldRate));

EditText rawEliteRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.eliteRate));

//there's more but I skipped it
}
```

LOGCAT of the crash:

FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.ajaydubey.fifamobilebulktradeprofitcounter, PID: 17627 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ajaydubey.fifamobilebulktradeprofitcounter/com.ajaydubey.fifamobilebulktradeprofitcounter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334) at com.ajaydubey.fifamobilebulktradeprofitcounter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)

I'm new to android to pardon any silly mistakes

Comment: provide logcat of crash.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Though I have posted the answer. but for your knowledge in Android studio at bottom there is a tab "Android Monitor" click on it and when your app crashes it will show the error in RED text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your views inside onCreate method like This and perform empty input Check on finInvString:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //setting up the elements
    EditText finInv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.finInv);
    String finInvString= finInv.getText().toString();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(finInvString){ // Do make sure to set android:inputType="number" in your XML layout file.
        int investment=Integer.parseInt(finInvString);
    }
    Button button14=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);

    EditText rawBroRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.bronzeRate));

    EditText rawSilRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.silverRate));

    EditText rawGoldRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.goldRate));

    EditText rawEliteRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.eliteRate));
}



}
```

** UPDATE **

in your Layout file add this tag to your EditText Element with id finInv:

> `android:inputType="number"`

Comment: I did that, the app is still crashing

Comment: please Show your Log.

Comment: ok got your issue. set android:inputType="number"  to your editText in your xml file.

Comment: hey its not crashing now.

Comment: great. the crash was NumberFormatException. it happens when you try to convert a non-numeric string e.g alphabets to integer or double etc. since the your edit text was accepting all the input even alphabets the conversion of your EditText fields text to int was throwing NumberFormatException and your app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it inside the `onCreate()` method and not outside since during the initialization you did not set a view with `setContentView(..)` e.g. fix it like this

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     EditText finInv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finInv);
     String finInvString = finInv.getText().toString();
     int investment = Integer.parseInt(finInvString);
     Button button14 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button14);
     EditText rawBroRate = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.bronzeRate));
     EditText rawSilRate = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.silverRate));
     EditText rawGoldRate = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.goldRate));
     EditText rawEliteRate = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.eliteRate));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

your initialization should be inside the onCreate method.
please have a look this code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//setting up the elements
EditText finInv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.finInv);
String finInvString= finInv.getText().toString();
int investment=Integer.parseInt(finInvString);

Button button14=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);

EditText rawBroRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.bronzeRate));

EditText rawSilRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.silverRate));

EditText rawGoldRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.goldRate));

EditText rawEliteRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.eliteRate));
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you app crashes with NullPointerException in the line 
`String finInvString= finInv.getText().toString();` as the finInv is referred even before the 'setContentView' is invoked.  Check your 'adb logcat' output.

Try,

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Member variables
    EditText finInv;

    Button button14;

    EditText rawBroRate;

    EditText rawSilRate;

    EditText rawGoldRate;

    EditText rawEliteRate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //setting up the elements
        finInv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.finInv);
        String finInvString= finInv.getText().toString();
        int investment=Integer.parseInt(finInvString);

        button14=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);

        rawBroRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.bronzeRate));

        rawSilRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.silverRate));

        rawGoldRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.goldRate));

        rawEliteRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.eliteRate));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.*;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
myinitialization();
    }
    public void myinitialization(){
    //setting up the elements
    EditText finInv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.finInv);
    String finInvString= finInv.getText().toString();
    int investment=Integer.parseInt(finInvString);

    Button button14=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button14);

    EditText rawBroRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.bronzeRate));

    EditText rawSilRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.silverRate));

    EditText rawGoldRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.goldRate));

    EditText rawEliteRate=((EditText) findViewById(R.id.eliteRate));

    //there's more but I skipped it
}
    }
```